# Webpack 4 SplitChunks outputting different chunk files in production and development mode

Tags: webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

Is it normal for splitChunks to output different files in Production and Development mode? Is it possible to make sure the number/name of outputted files is the same between modes?

This is my config:

```
splitChunks: {
       cacheGroups: {
           vendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/i,
              chunks: "all",
              reuseExistingChunk: true
           }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of Webpack `SplitChunksPlugin`. By [default](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#defaults), in production mode, any chunk smaller than 30kb will be ignored.

You can enforce a minimum chunk size by setting `optimization.splitChunks.minSize` [option](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksminsize) to a value smaller than your smallest chunk in development mode, to ensure the same chunks and created in both development and production modes.